# Getting confused with how to apply inequality

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

**A random variable X is defined by the transformation Z = log(X), where the mean of the random variable Z is E(Z) = 0. Is E(X) greater than, less than, or equal to 1?**

I know we need to apply Jensens Inequality, And I know that $X= e^Z$. But am getting really confused on what is E(X).

Comment: $E(X)=E(\exp(Z))$. Note that $\exp$ is a convex function/

Comment: How do I use the E(Z)=0 fact though?, this is a textbook problem with no clarification regarding the answer, so just want to confirm how you solve it.

Comment: @JohnSmith That's exactly what Jensen's inequality is for: comparing $E(e^Z)$ to $e^{E(Z)}$. Also, this site isn't really for confirming how we would solve something. It's about us helping you to solve it yourself. At least, some of us strive for that.

Comment: So is $e^z$ a function of X? Or a function of Z? That's whats confusing me. Can we write $g(X)=e^z$? Basically, writing an substituting Jensen's inequality is confusing me.

Comment: $e^z$ is a function of $z$. Mind you, there is no $z$ in the problem $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Then where do we get the E(X) term while setting up Jensen's inequality? That's basically the only issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

Jensen's inequality should be thought of independently of expectations and probabilities.

It's just a statement that the weighted average of a convex function evaluated at a number of points is at least as great as the function evaluated at the weighted average of the points. So for a convex function $f$, this means that$$
w_1 \, f(x_1) + w_2 \, f(x_2) + \ldots + w_n \, f(x_n) \ge f(w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \ldots + w_n x_n)
$$ where $$
w_i \ge 0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1.
$$

If you pick $n=2$, you can see this immediately by noticing that a convex function always lies below the line connecting any two of its points [image: Convex function lies below the line connecting two of its points]

Tying back to probabilities and expectations, notice that expectations are weighted averages, and that the function $f(x) = \exp(x)$ is convex. So the expectation of $f(x)$ will be greater than $f( \text{expectation}(x) )$.